# Tipsy Tooltip jquery Multi Not Worked

Tags: jquery, tooltip

Tipsy Is lightweight and great technology for facebook tooltip style. now i need to this for multiple link. eg :

```
<table id=\"gravity\">
   <tr height=\"22\">
       <td width=\"1%\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">
            <a id=\"foo\" title=\"test\" href=\"#\" > $id</a> //$id dynamic id for link 1, 2, 3, ...
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Js included is :

```
$(function() {
$('#foo').tipsy({gravity: 's'}); });
```

This Worked For me But print and show only first id (first link) and next link now show tipsy. what's Problem ? how to work for multiple link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the plugin to apply on all the links then change the selector to match all those links. Best is give a class `tipsy` or watever you name to all the links and find them using class selector. Try this.

Markup (Note: I  have added class="tipsy" to the link)

```
<table id=\"gravity\">
   <tr height=\"22\">
       <td width=\"1%\" align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"$bgcolor\">
            <a id=\"foo\" class=\"tipsy\" title=\"test\" href=\"#\" > $id</a> //$id dynamic id for link 1, 2, 3, ...
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('a.tipsy').tipsy({gravity: 's'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The tipsy plugin binds an event to the link currently in #foo.  If you dynamically change it, you may need to re-bind tipsy to it.

Try appending $('#foo').tipsy({gravity: 's'}); }); to the function that changes the link.